# Manually edit an individual row in phppgadmin

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update, phppgadmin

I would just like to edit manually WITHOUT using a query in phppgadmin is it possible?

[image: 1]

I can only see the list of the contents of the table when i click browse, seems like there is no edit row button here as well

[image: 2]

at the bottom of the pages the only options are Back, Expand, Insert, Refresh

Any help will do thanks for reading.

Comment: When there is a primary key, you can do it. Otherwise not possible. Offtopic: Why did you choose a VARCHAR for the column "permission" when you store an array of integers? I would normalise this data to integers or use at least an integer array.

Comment: i see, so im assuming an sql statement is the only way if there is no primary key. and thanks for pointing out the offtopic ill discuss this with the one who made the table